# Adding a single text input field to a custom Dashboard widget

Tags: widgets, admin, forms, dashboard, input

I have a client whom I want to give as much Dashboard control over the admin area as possible. I know how to create a custom dashboard widget that contains just text/html but I have no idea how to create one that contains just a single text input field.

Adding the form html would be straightforward I can see that but I don't know:

1. Where to submit the form data too
2. How to redirect back to the Dashboard after the form is submitted
3. How to retrieve the value in my non-admin theme templates

Answer (score 1):

You need a set of functions to :

- process datas
- sanitize options
- allow datas to be updated
- output the form

I like to proceed this way. I set also a function to grab datas so I can call them the simpliest way :

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_106458_add_widget');

function wpse_106458_add_widget() {

  $title = my_function_get_options();
  $title = $title['title'];

  wp_add_dashboard_widget('widget_id', $title, 'callback_output', 'widget_control' );
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** I wrap it with this :

```
if ( is_admin() || ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || !DOING_AJAX ) ) {/* code goes here */}
```

This allows to apply code only where it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help :)

I came across this script which I removed from the Theme page and inserted into a Dashboard Widget via functions.php it helped a lot: http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/